# How to remove NaN error from Telerik MVC Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Ajax Bound Teleric MVC 2 Grid . When there is no data in Grid , Grid footer is showing me a message as " Displaying items 0 - NaN of " ... how to remove or modify this error and correct the same ?

[image: How to remove this Nan Problem ?]

Comment: It looks like it is a bug (might have been patched) check out this thread http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/paging-info-text-bug-if-grid-is-empty.aspx

Comment: I have already gone through that link and updated my Javascript file with the file given by Atanas but its not working .... There are so many bugs in Telerik MVC controls which they have never tried to resolve rather they expect developers like us to resolve on our own .. This is totally insane

Comment: I would make sure that you properly included the JavaScript file, there could still be potential issues with old references. As for the bugs it seems like it would be a good idea to post in the Telerik forums to get some help and/or workarounds with those. As you can see in the linked thread a fix is usually provided pretty quickly.

Comment: i have checked telerik forums and also i have properly included js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of older versions of Telerik ASP.NET MVC Extensions. Upgrade to the latest version (currently Q1 2012 - 2012.1.214) to fix this bug and others (like Ajax Grid error handling).

Install the latest version using Nuget:

```
Install-Package TelerikMvcExtensions
```

Or update previous versions that are installed with Nuget:

```
Update-Package TelerikMvcExtensions
```